# How to launch a exe from wix msi/bootstrapper for registration purpose?

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer

How to launch an exe, for registration purpose, which is bundled into Msi? and on successful registration, it creates a file in target system and then i want to continue the installation.

Till date i used InstallShield/support dir item and now i want to use Wix to package my installer.

1. Is it possible with Wix packaging?
2. Any limitations to do so?, since i want to launch that registration exe as soon as installation has started.
3. Is there any different methods to overcome it?

Comment: What does "registration purpose" mean? If it's COM or the GAC you don't need to run an exe. If it's customer registration, then you'd run it as a custom action. Either way, if you start it as soon as the install starts you'd need to worry about about an installation failure that would leave the registration there even though the install failed, but I guess you've already been doing that.. You'd run the exe out of the Binary table. Might help http://sourceforge.net/p/wix/mailman/message/15944342/

Comment: Thanks for your comment, PhilDW. Exactly it is a customer registration and this exe has some dependencies for successfully registration which are also packaged along it. In this case, how to launch a exe with dependencies from a msi custom action?. Please correct me If i am in wrong process. Thanks.

Comment: You didn't mention dependencies before, but basically you're still just running it as a custom action, and if the exe includes the program and its dependencies then it should just work. Here's an example of a CA from the Binary table http://blogs.technet.com/b/alexshev/archive/2008/02/21/from-msi-to-wix-part-5-custom-actions.aspx and I don't know why the IS supportdir was necessary for you - it's just a temp location, and Windows will use a temp location for that kind of CA anyway.